# Bash thinks input is incorrect when it is?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have this script, but on line 51, when I answer "y", bash skips that and tells me to "answer y or n" (skips to line 58):

```
debianDeps() {
    apt-get install git cmake build-essential liblua5.2-dev \
        libgmp3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libboost-system-dev
}

fedoraDeps() {
    yum install git cmake gcc-c++ boost-devel \
        gmp-devel community-mysql-devel lua-devel
}

bsdDeps() {
    cd /usr/ports/shells/bash && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/devel/git && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/devel/cmake && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/lang/gcc47 && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/lang/luajit && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/devel/boost-libs && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/math/gmp && make install clean BATCH=yes
    cd /usr/ports/databases/mysql-connector-c && make install clean BATCH=yes
}

libInstall() {
    echo "Libraries and Build Tools... Installed"
}

bsdBuild() {
    echo "Building on FreeBSD"
    mkdir build && cd build
    CXX=g++47 cmake ..
    echo "Build on $cpuCores threads with $coreBuild processes? (experimental but loads faster) y or n "
        read $ans1_4
            if [[ $ans1_4 = "y" ]]; then
                echo -e $greenText"Building on $cpuCores threads with $coreBuild ."$none
                make -j $coreBuild
            elif [[ $ans1_4 = "n" ]]; then
                echo -e $blueText"Building on a single thread."$none
                make
            else
                echo "answer y or n"
                echo -e $redText"Answer y or n"$none
            fi
}   

genBuild() {
    echo "Building..."
    mkdir build && cd build
    cmake ..
        echo "Build on $cpuCores threads with $coreBuild processes? (experimental but loads faster) y or n "
        read $ans1_4
            if [[ $ans1_4 = "y" ]]; then
                echo -e $greenText"Building on $cpuCores threads with $coreBuild ."$none
                make -j $coreBuild
            elif [[ $ans1_4 = "n" ]]; then
                echo -e $blueText"Building on a single thread."$none
                make
            else
                echo -e $redText"Answer y or n"$none
            fi              
}

clean() {
    mkdir objs/
    mv *.o objs/
    echo "There might be a few leftover files."
}

###
### Script starts here
###

#check if root
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "You must be root to use this script, press enter to exit."
    read end
    exit 1
fi
#OS dependencies and other stuff
echo "Chose your Operating System. {Supported OS: Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, FreeBSD} "
read ans1 

if [[ $ans1 = "Fedora" ]] || [[ $nas1 = "CentOS" ]]; then
    echo -n "Should the script install dependencies? y or n"
    read ans1_1
    if [[ $ans1_1 = "y" ]]; then
        fedoraDeps
    elif [[ $ans1_1 = "n" ]]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Answer 'y' or 'n' "
    fi
elif [[ $ans1 = "Debian" ]] || [[ $ans1 = "Ubuntu" ]]; then
    echo -n "Should the script install dependencies? y or n"
    read ans1_1
    if [[ $ans1_1 = "y" ]]; then
        debianDeps
    elif [[ $ans1_1 = "n" ]]; then
        break
    else
        echo "Answer 'y' or 'n' "
    fi
elif [[ $ans1 = "FreeBSD" ]]; then
    echo -n "Should the script install dependencies? y or n"
    read ans1_1
        if [[ $ans1_1 = "y" ]]; then
            bsdDeps
        elif [[ $ans1_1 = "n" ]]; then
            break
        else
            echo "Answer 'y' or 'n' "
        fi              
        else
            echo "Pick a valid OS"      
        fi

#Compiling here

echo -n "Are we on FreeBSD? y or n"
read ans1_2
    if [[ $ans1_2 = "y" ]]; then
        bsdbuild
    elif [[ $ans1_2 = "n" ]]; then
        genBuild
    else
        echo "Answer y or n"
    fi

echo "Should the folder be cleaned? y or n"
    read ans1_3
    if [[ $ans1_3 = "y" ]]; then
        clean
    elif [[ $ans1_3 = "n" ]]; then
        echo "Exiting..."
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Answer y or n"
    fi
```

Comment: Why are you typing a $ in front of the variable when you `read` it?

Comment: You are encouraged to add the relevant portion of your problem to your question, links disappear, and people may want to find answers on their searches. But in short: `read $ans1_4` => `read ans1_4`. Note that using `set -x` really helps in debugging bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

`read $ans1_4` should be `read ans1_4` I made a little mistake there.